# Quick way of drawing Hasse diagrams of posets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

When drawing a Hasse diagram, I have seen that you can draw a bigraph for the poset and remove the reflexive and transitive edges of the poset. However, doing this for a poset with many elements can get tedious (by hand).

Is there a more efficient way of drawing a Hasse diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known as [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction). It is shown equivalent to multiplication of binary matrices. A simple $n^3$ algorithm (so pretty good in regards of matrix multiplication) is as follow : Compute the transitive closure then find transitive edges by iterating over all sets of 3 vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large poset, a computer is probably useful. The wikipedia entry [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) gives two interesting references:

[1] Di Battista, G.; Tamassia, R. (1988), Algorithms for plane representation of acyclic digraphs, *Theoretical Computer Science* **61** (2–3): 175–178.

[2] Freese, Ralph (2004), [Automated lattice drawing](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Eralph/Preprints/latdrawing.pdf), Concept Lattices, LNCS 2961, Springer-Verlag, 589–590.